# How to use SQL Server query to put data at group level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, grouping

Currently the query I wrote as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 15 
    SalesRegion AS [Sales_Region], 
    Year(ModifiedDate) AS [Fiscal Year], 
    Total AS [Sales Amount]
FROM dbo.SalesReport
ORDER BY SalesRegion;
```

And when put the query out using SSRS, it looks like this:

[image]

Now what I want to do is to create a group for `SalesRegion`, and the result should look like this:

[image]

What kind of changes should I make to the query in order to generate the result like that?

Comment: You really wouldn't need to change your query. simple create a row group that is grouped on Sales Region and a child group to show detail without a grouping.The rest is all formatting the sales region textbox to get the look that you are going for

Comment: @SFrejofsky This solved the problem i had. Can you post this to the answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query as it stands would work for your purpose.

1. Create a Row Group that is grouped on Sales Region.
2. Create a Child group to show detail without a grouping.

Then it is just a matter of formatting the textbox to achieve the look that you want.